# Is there a website that will let me see add markers and bounding boxes on top of a street map?

Tags: extents

Is there a website out there that will let me markers (lat/lon) and bounding boxes (minimum / maximum lat/lon) and let me see it overlayed on top of Google Maps (or OSM, or Bing, etc)? I'm not really looking to create my own webpage for this... I'm hoping someone's implemented something like this for a general use case or a demo and it's online somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Google Maps Example:**

You can run this example from you local drive.

[image]

You could simply add a form to enter the coords rather than the code.

for changing the extents set the 
new google.maps.Rectangle({
        bounds:new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(**37.2, -122.3**), new google.maps.LatLng(**37.6, -121.9**)), to the values you want.

```
new google.maps.Rectangle({
    bounds:new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(37.2, -122.3), new google.maps.LatLng(37.6, -121.9)),
    map:map,
    fillOpacity: 0.2,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
    strokeWeight: 1
  });
```

http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/rectangle_example.html

**Open Street Map Example:**

For Open Street Map you can just call the API to generate a simple rectangle by adding **&box=yes** to the call

[image]

http://www.openstreetmap.org/?minlon=-0.489&minlat=51.28&maxlon=0.236&maxlat=51.686&box=yes

Comment: osm doesnt seem to display a bbox anymore.

Comment: @sal try http://tools.geofabrik.de/calc/#type=geofabrik_standard&bbox=5.538062,47.236312,15.371071,54.954937&tab=1&proj=EPSG:4326&places=2 now looks like osm changed their setup

Comment: Regarding the google maps solution, the OP did not ask for code snippets, but for an existing service. I provide this here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/220247/37448

Answer (score 7):

This will let you enter and display a bounding box on an OSM background: https://linestrings.com/bbox/#12,52,14,53 (add bbox as url hash to share map with box)

[image]

Alternatively, I also found bboxfinder quite nice: http://bboxfinder.com/#-16.636192,-69.433594,-1.581830,-51.503906

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this will meet your requirements:
http://mapper.acme.com/

Comment: This has markers, but I don't see a way to add a bounding box.

Comment: Gotcha, the easiest way then would be just to take the bottom sample from Mapperz solution and change the bounding box.

Answer (score -1):

The following site seems to be what you're looking for:

http://boundingbox.klokantech.com/

[image]

Comment: No, it does not. This works only in the other way around - click on map and get bounding box.

Comment: this is the inverse of what was asked

Answer (score -1):

You can use http://geojson.io to upload and view markers and polygons in KML, csv, and json format, or you can draw them in the web interface then save to CSV, KML, shapefile, or json formats.

[image]

Comment: geojson.io can display a bbox if the bbox is provided as a polygon in geojson format, which is some overhead if someone just wants a quick bbox visualized.

Comment: If your bounding box is not in json, csv, KML, etc. format, you can draw a box, then edit the coordinates in the json text within the right-hand panel.